# Error in scikit-image example: RAG Thresholding

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am new the the scikit-learning package, I was going through some of the tutorials and came to this example : http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_rag_mean_color.html#example-plot-rag-mean-color-py

```
from skimage import graph, data, io, segmentation, color
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = data.coffee()

labels1 = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=30, n_segments=400)
out1 = color.label2rgb(labels1, img, kind='avg')

g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels1)
labels2 = graph.cut_threshold(labels1, g, 29)
out2 = color.label2rgb(labels2, img, kind='avg')

plt.figure()
io.imshow(out1)
plt.figure()
io.imshow(out2)
io.show()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ColorThresh.py", line 8, in <module>
out1 = color.label2rgb(labels1, img, kind='avg')
TypeError: label2rgb() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'
```

Documentation on function:

**http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html?highlight=label2rgb#skimage.color.label2rgb**

I am running on ubuntu 14.04

scikit-image (0.10.1)

python (2.7.6)

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i have try your code. Also On Ubuntu 14.04. **ITS WORK WELL**
I just install *scipy* : http://www.scipy.org/

or you can install manual with pip this all list :

```
# pip install numpy --upgrade
# pip install scipy --upgrade
# pip install matplotlib --upgrade
# pip install ipython --upgrade
# pip install pandas --upgrade
# pip install sympy --upgrade
# pip install nose --upgrade
```